# Getting 'No code was generated' error when trying to create web service proxy using SVCUTIL.EXE

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

When trying to create a web service proxy (WCF) using `SVCUTIL.EXE` (on command line or via Visual Studio) I get the below nonsensical error message.

Note: There is nothing wrong with the service as it works on another machine just fine. It's a new install of Windows and the service is on my local box. Generating the same proxy on my machine using a URL on a different machine works fine.

What's going on?!

```
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'https://ws1.example.com/ShoppingCartWS/WCF/ShoppingCartWCF.svc?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchan
Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageCont
Error: Schema with target namespace '' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='IShoppingCart']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='IShoppingCart']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IShoppingCart']   

.....    

Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='IShoppingCart']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IShoppingCart1']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IShoppingCart1']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='ShoppingCartWCF']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IShoppingCart1']


Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.
```

Answer (score 6):

This `Warning: No code was generated` error message can be triggered by lack of permissions to the app pool user on the `C:\Windows\Temp` directory (yes really!)

If you're getting this error I first suggest you switch to the command line if you're trying to use the 'Add Service Reference' dialog. Run this command with Fiddler open for your service URL.

```
 svcutil.exe https://dev.example.com/ShoppingCartWS/WCF/ShoppingCartWCF.svc?wsdl
```

If you see any of the requests come back as 500 (in red) and the following response then you're probably having the same issue as I did.

```
ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

Just check `C:\Windows\Temp` and just add whatever user your app pool is running at to have permissions. I just cheated and added `Everyone`, but if security is important you should find the correct app pool username from IIS.

[This is where I found the solution - many thanks!](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/raimondb/archive/2008/02/14/Unable-to-generate-a-WCF-proxy-using-svcutil-but-retreiving-the-wsdl-works_3F00_.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't your answer only explain `Warning: No code was generated.`? How does this resolve the errors you're getting?

Comment: site address isn't available anymore. By other way, I dont hava any 500 but still cannot add references.